# How to create a JKS file using public and private keys for spring saml application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml, shibboleth

I am accessing the spring saml application using `shibboleth` single sign on. Instead of using `samlkeystore.jks` file I want to create my own `test.jks`. I have created the JKS certificate using :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -name xxx -in selfsignedcert.crt -inkey serverprivatekey.key -out myp12keystore.p12

Keytool for p12 > JKS

keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore mykeystore.jks -srckeystore myp12keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -alias xxx
```

I have made changes in `securityContaext.xml`, like file name, password and alias.
But when accessing SP, I am getting error like:

Message:

> Cannot sign outgoing message as no signing credential is set
>   in the context

StackTrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot sign outgoing message as no
>   signing credential is set in the context  at
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)

Please help on how to correct this?

Comment: This may help you: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-profiles

Answer (score 0):

If you try to create the keypair without any kind of transformation p12 --> jks, does it work?

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias myKey -keypass changeit -keystore mykeystore.jks
```

And put these to the securityContext.xml
Alias: myKey
Password: changeit

Like this:

```
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/mykeystore.jks"/>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="changeit"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="myKey" value="changeit"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="myKey"/>
    </bean>
```